# Is there a way to show missing values as a row in df with groupby()?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby, pandas.excelwriter

I have 3 dfs which need to be aggregated at customer type and count by office visit in each location.

The goal is to output these 3 dfs in one excel sheet and have each final output table has the exact same number of rows (all customer type in the same order).

However, since not all df has all the customer types, is there any way to get the desired output?
Below is the code (which I simplified the data):

```
d1 = {'customer type':['walk in', 'online app', 'phone app', 'referral'], 'office visit': 
['location1','location1','location1','location1']}
df1=pd.DataFrame(data=d1)

d2 = {'customer type': ['walk in', 'online app', 'phone app'], 'office visit': 
['location1','location1','location1']}
df2=pd.DataFrame(data=d2)

d3={'customer type':['walk in','referral'],'office visit':['location1','location1']}
df3=pd.DataFrame(data=d3)

def info(df):
    df=df.groupby(['customer type','office visit'],sort=True).size().unstack().fillna(0)
    return df

df1=info(df1)
df2=info(df2)
df3=info(df3)

with pd.ExcelWriter(r'C:\users\JZ\patient.xlsx',engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
    df1.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='patient',startrow=0,startcol=0)
    df2.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='patient',startrow=0, startcol=5)
    df3.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='patient',startrow=0, startcol=10)
```

The desired output would be all 3 dfs would have 4 rows (each row show each customer type - online app, phone app, referral and walk in) regardless of they have all customer type or not. For df2, referral would be 0. for df3, online app and phone app would both be 0.

Any helps and advices would be highly appreciated.

Comment: `pd.concat([info(d) for d in [df1,df2,df3]], axis=1).fillna(0).to_excel(...)`?

Comment: Thanks Quang for the advice, but I need 3 df in the output not 1 because they have a different time period.